# Problemas com caracteres especiais á, ç, à, etc com php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Olá, estou realizando um get de arquivos da database para um página com o fim de ser uma barra de pesquisa, porém todos os resultados obtidos não estão aceitando caractéres especiais, tais como: ç, á, è.

> ex: LEGISLA��O APLIC�VEL

HTML/PHP:

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Pesquisa...">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button submit" name="submit-search">Buscar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form> <br>
      <!-- Search bar -->

<?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
        $queryResults = mysqli_num_rows ($result);

        if ($queryResults > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<div class='article-box'>
                    <h3>".$row['nome']."</h3>
                    <p>".$row['descricao']."</p>
                    <p>Relator: ".$row['relator']."</p>
                    <p>Data: ".$row['data']."</p>
                  </div>";
            }
        }
?>
```

Conexão:

```
<?php
define('HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('USUARIO', 'root');
define('SENHA', 'senha');
define('DB', 'dbname');

$conexao = mysqli_connect(HOST, USUARIO, SENHA, DB) or die ('Não foi possivel conectar!');

?>
```

Meta usada no html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

A collation da database, conexão e editor (Visual Studio Code) são:

```
utf8_general_ci
```

Já tentei trocar a collation de tudo para latin1_general_ci, porém também não obtive sucesso.

O comando SET NAMES utf8 também não surtiu resultado.

Na head do html está no formato `<html lang="pt-BR">`

Gostaria de uma luz neste problema.

Desde já, agradeço a paciência!

Comment: @PedroAugusto A solução daquela outra pergunta não surtiu resultado.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> tenta assim

Comment: @Sr.AndréBaill Também não houve nenhuma mudança

Comment: poderia me mostra sua conxeão com o banco ?

Comment: @PauloVictor Posso não ter entendido direito, mas seria o código que efetua a conexão do banco? Se for este caso, atualizei a pergunta com o código.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss A solução foi adicionar a config de charset na conexão do banco descrito na outra pergunta, obrigado pela informação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com a ajuda dos comentários obtive um solução para este problema. Sendo ela:

Foi necessário especificar o charset na conexão do banco, juntamente com o padrão de meta charset's já adicionado na pergunta (sendo utf8).

Linha de código necessária:

```
if (!mysqli_set_charset($conexao, 'utf8')) {
    printf('Error ao usar utf8: %s', mysqli_error($conexao));
    exit;
}
```

Agradeço a todos que ajudaram nos comentários da pergunta, e pela possíveis duplicatas que vieram a solucionar o problema.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta utilizar os comandos

```
utf8_decode()
utf8_encode()
```

Trabalhei em um sistema onde cada tabela do banco tinha uma codificação diferente, o que eu tinha que fazer era `utf8_decode(utf8_encode($texto))`

Comment: Apesar de estar usando a mesma codificação para o banco inteiro, não conhecia esta opção determinada para o texto, o problema foi resolvido na conexão mas agradeço a informação, acredito que ela será útil futuramente.